# How to change button color onclick using javascript only?

Tags: javascript, onclick, getelementsbyclassname

I was trying to make the color of the buttons change using onclick and getElementsByClassName and came up with something like this:

HTML:

```
<button onclick="submitButtonStyle()" type="submit" class="stylebutton"> 
Submit </button>
```

JS:

```
function submitButtonStyle() { 
document.getElementsByClassName("stylebutton").style.backgroundColor = "red"; }﻿
```

I would be really grateful if you guys gave me a hint about what is lacking in my code/what I should add etc.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`getElementsByClassName` returns an `HTMLCollection` so you need to get the elements using an index, in your case index === 0 `getElementsByClassName[0]`.

Actually, you don't need to call the function `getElementsByClassName`, pass the element as param.

```js
function submitButtonStyle(_this) {
  _this.style.backgroundColor = "red";
}
```

```html
<button onclick="submitButtonStyle(this)" type="submit" class="stylebutton"> 
Submit </button>
```

**Better approach using Event binding and function `querySelectorAll`**

```js
document.querySelectorAll('.stylebutton').forEach(function(e) {
  e.addEventListener('click', function() {
    this.style.backgroundColor = "red";
  })
});
```

```html
<button type="submit" class="stylebutton"> Submit </button>
```

Answer (score 2):

`document.getElementsByClassName` returns an array of objects, since many tags may have the same class. If you know that only one object has a given class, use

```
document.getElementsByClassName("stylebutton")[0].style.backgroundColor = "red";
```

Answer (score 0):

The className property sets or returns the class name of an element (the value of an element's class attribute).

```js
function submitButtonStyle() { 
document.getElementsByClassName("stylebutton")[0].style.backgroundColor = "red"; }
```

```html
<button onclick="submitButtonStyle()" type="submit" class="stylebutton"> 
Submit </button>
JS:
```

> The getElementsByClassName() method returns a collection of all
>   elements in the document with the specified class name, as a NodeList
>   object.
>
> The NodeList object represents a collection of nodes. The nodes can be
>   accessed by index numbers. The index starts at 0.

[Source](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_document_getelementsbyclassname.asp)

Answer (score 0):

Using jquery, try this. if your button id is say id= clickme

```
$("clickme").on('çlick', function(){

    $(this).css('background-color', 'grey'); .......
```