# How to change two different background colors in JavaScript using onClick() event for two buttons

Tags: javascript, html

I have to make two buttons that will change the background color onclick, the first button will change the background color to yellow and the other one will change the background color into light blue. I have done something like this,

```html
<button id="bttn1" type="button" onclick="changeColor()">Click for a yellow color</button>
<button id="bttn2" type="button" onclick="changeColor()">Click for a light blue color</button>
```

```js
function changeColor() {
  document.getElementById("bttn1").style.backgroundColor = "yellow";
  document.getElementById("bttn2").style.backgroundColor = "light blue";
}
```

Comment: background-color of buttons or webpage?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to change button color onclick using javascript only?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48845033/how-to-change-button-color-onclick-using-javascript-only)

Comment: Its `lightblue` not `light blue`

Comment: This is very low quality question :<

Comment: im new to this :( im sorry

Comment: @TyaaJaynar I mean your problem can solve by just removing space . I just want to point that low research effort :) sorry if it’s like offended you :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

set the color using **document.body.style.background**

```html
<script type="text/javascript">
function changeColor(color){
    document.body.style.background = color;
}
</script>
<button id="bttn1" type="button" onclick="changeColor('yellow')">Click for a yellow color</button>
<button id="bttn2" type="button" onclick="changeColor('lightblue')">Click for a light blue color</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

For changing the button background

```
    <script>
                function changeColorYellow() 
                {
                  document.getElementById("bttn1").style.backgroundColor = "yellow";
                }
                function changeColorLightBlue() 
                {
                  document.getElementById("bttn2").style.backgroundColor = "LightBlue";
                }
                </script>
```

For changing background-color

```
    function changeColorYellow() {
        document.querySelector('body').style.backgroundColor = "yellow";
    }
    function changeColorLightBlue() {
        document.querySelector('body').style.backgroundColor = "LightBlue";
    }
```

Add CSS with it

```
body {
    height:100vh;
    width:100wh;
}
```

And change the HTML respectively...

Answer (score 0):

If you are just trying to change the color of the webpage then you could do something like

```html
<button id="bttn1" type="button" onclick="changeColor("yellow")">Click for a yellow color</button>
<button id="bttn2" type="button" onclick="changeColor("lightblue")">Click for a light blue color</button>
```

```js
function changeColor(color) {
  document.body.style.backgroundColor = color;
}
```

Comment: why are you posting same answer already given by some one else.

Comment: my answer shows how to change the webpage color not the button color, answering the question asked not saying what the other said